# When will we have a special design template?

Tags: feature-request

When will Islam.SE  have a special design like ones that can be found in [Christianity.SE](http://christianity.stackexchange.com) or  [Judaism.SE](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites that are still in beta (such as us) all use the same design template.  When a site graduates, a new design for the site is developed by the Stack Exchange creative design team (with the input of the community) and applied.

As for when will this site graduate, you can check out this blog post: "[When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)".  In short, we'll graduate when the Stack Exchange team feels we as a community and as a site have matured to the point where users can reasonably expect expert answers to their questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :)